# Is there a way to disable timestamp columns globally for all models?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I can disable the timestamp columns for a particular model but is there a way to disable it for all models?

```
const Contract = sequelize.define('Contract', {
    idContract: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    AccountNo_Lender: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, { timestamps: false });
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can define this when initializing the `sequelize` object.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
});
```

Options under `define` are as same as when we define them inside the model. So all the options which can be used inside the model can be used here as well. From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html#options)

> // Specify options, which are used when sequelize.define is called.
>   // The following example:   //   define: { timestamps: false }   // is
>   basically the same as:   //   sequelize.define(name, attributes, {
>   timestamps: false })   // so defining the timestamps for each model
>   will be not necessary

Answer (score 2):

The Sequelize constructor takes a define option which will change the default options for all defined models.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(connectionURI, {
  define: {
    // The `timestamps` field specify whether or not the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields will be created.
    // This was true by default, but now is false by default
    timestamps: false
  }
});

// Here `timestamps` will be false, so the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields will not be created.
class Foo extends Model {}
Foo.init({ /* ... */ }, { sequelize });

// Here `timestamps` is directly set to true, so the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields will be created.
class Bar extends Model {}
Bar.init({ /* ... */ }, { sequelize, timestamps: true });
```

[docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/getting-started.html)